# Make one div overlap another?

Tags: html, css

I've got a line of text that gets revealed when a dropdown arrow is clicked. However, certain pages of the site I'm building have divs that extend beyond the single line of text I'm hiding.

Here's an example:

[image]

The green div (ordinarily white) needs to overlap the div above (blue body with orange margins). My goal is to cover up a link that will sit 15px beneath the arrow under the word "Bukau", leaving the text to left unaffected.

I have a hunch the solution I'm looking for might involve making the 'green' div fixed/changing z-index values.

I also want to make sure the green block acts like an extension of the content below it, getting pulled up/down when a user clicks the arrow toggle.

Appreciate any advice/suggestions!

Comment: share fiddle link

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRPjrB

Comment: ^^^ It's a bit of a mess (more than a bit, haha), but hopefully it'll provide some insight regarding what I'm trying to do.

Keep in mind: the text I'm trying to cover (in the codepen example I've shared) is not where it will be ultimately. I'm more concerned with getting the white div below to extend beyond the border of the div above it when the toggle (missing icon in pen but functional) is selected

Comment: Eager to figure this out, happy to provide additional context if needed!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Understood. I suppose I believed my question "Make one div overlap another" and the stated goal in the description (covering and revealing a bit of text with the aformentioned div) did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Simple as making the top-margin on the 'green' div -50 or so pixels, and setting its position to 'relative'